# Java convert float to byte on custom terms

Tags: java, floating-point, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

I want to write/read millions of numbers from 0-15 from/to a file. Precision is not an issue, as long as the read values are within +-0.1 of the written one, everything is fine.

## Previous Ideas

My first, premature idea was to convert a float to a String like this and write them space-separated:

```
String.format("%.1f%s", float)
```

This, of course, is very inefficient, as it uses 4-5 bytes for every float.

Then I came to the idea to just write the bytes of each float, that would be faster but not sufficiently reduce the size.

```
ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(float).array()
```

## Current issue

My current idea is to reduce the float to one byte. Looking at the ranges and precision I need, I would allocate the first 4 bits to represent the decimals before the floating point and the last 4 bits to the tail.

But how can I obtain these bits fast, since it has to be done millions of times?

Comment: Wouldn't `x * 255 / 15` work?

Comment: and how do I obtain the byte I need?

Comment: @Xerus: Um, precisely by multiplying by 255, dividing by 15, then casting to `byte`. So something like `byte b = (byte) (f * 255.0f / 15.0f);`

Comment: How is multiplying by 255 then dividing by 15 any different from just multiplying by 17?  Why do two operations when you can do one?  And since OP is actually only concerned with one decimal place, it makes more sense just to multiply by 10.

Comment: actually, I didn't word this right. There might be more decimal places than one, but I only need the accuracy of one, that's why I want to allocate 4 bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use something like this:

```
//  conversion factor to map 15.0 to 0xF0
float m = (float) (0xF0 / 15.0);

for (float x = 0.0f; x <= 15.0f; x += 0.25f) {
    //  obtain byte corresponding to float
    byte b = (byte) (m * x);
    //  recover float from byte to check conversion
    //  mask off sign bit to convert signed to unsigned byte
    float r = (b & 0x0FF) / m;
    //  what is the difference between original float and 
    //  recovered float?
    float error = Math.abs(x - r);
    //  show all values for testing
    String s = " b=0x" + Integer.toHexString(b & 0x0FF) + 
               " r=" + Float.toString(r) + 
               " err=" + Float.toString(error);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: It seems to be what I need, but please add some explanations (and maybe use String.format for debug output)

Comment: @Xerus All he's doing is multiplying by 16 and casting the result to `byte`.  There's a big thwacking error when he converts it back to a `float`, because he doesn't round the result to one decimal place.  The rest of the code here is just for testing and display.

Comment: rounding to one decimal place is not needed, as long as the float that I read is within +-0.1 of the written one everything should be fine

Comment: I'm gonna use that, it's simple, clean and fast. Note: don't add 0.25 for testing, since it can be exactly represented as float and always leads to an error of 0. When going in steps of 0.01, the biggest error was 0.0625, which fulfills my criteria.

Comment: When `m * x` is converted to `byte` it will be truncated. This may truncate some values. E.g., what looks like 8.1 may be slightly below 8.1, so the result may be 80 instead of 81. And the sample program only checks multiples of .25, not .1.

Comment: @Eric Sure enough! As observed by Xerus, the error maximum is 0.06249976 (measured in x-steps of 0.05) which is OK for the intended purpose,

Answer (score 1):

Since your tail is single digit, it can be implicit - i.e. 14.3 is converted to 143. To convert back, it would simply be `143 / 10` to get whole part, and `143 % 10` to get the fraction. Here is how an implementation could look like.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float floatValue = 14.1f;
        Test test = new Test();
        byte b = test.toByteStorage(floatValue);
        System.out.println(test.fromByteStorage(b));
    }

    byte toByteStorage(float f) {
        return (byte) (f * 10);
    }

    String fromByteStorage(byte b) {
        int intValue = Byte.toUnsignedInt(b);
        return intValue / 10 + "." + intValue % 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: When `f * 10` is converted to `byte` it will be truncated. This may truncate some values. E.g., what looks like 8.1 may be slightly below 8.1, so the result may be 80 instead of 81.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Except this is for numbers 0 to 15 - the exponent in their float representation is small enough, that first decimal place will be precise (which is what OP wants). You're more than welcome to prove me wrong with a concrete example.

Comment: **Binary** floating point is not exact at even a single **decimal** point. I am traveling now and cannot provide an example today. But even if there are no examples with the OP’s particular parameters, this is an issue in floating point generally. At the least, `f * 10` ought to be rounded to an integer, not truncated. (This will not cure all the rounding issues in this code, but it will take care of the largest one.)

Comment: (Note: It is not clear from the OP’s question whether all input values will be very near multiples of .1. If they are not, then consider an input around 7.199. Multiplying by 10 produces about 71.99, and then truncation produces 71. But 72 would be better.)